# When a break is reached in PHP how many levels does it break out of?

Tags: php

Ok this may be an elementary question, but I want an informed answer and I can't seem to get the keywords right to get an answer through google. If this is a duplicate please close it and point me in the right direction.

So here's the question. In the code below, when the break that's pointed to is executed, where does it break out too?

```
case 'changeEmployeeInfo':
    $con = db_connect(DBNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD , DBHOST);
    $query = 'UPDATE USERS SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?, email = ? where idusers = ?';
    $updateValues = array($firstName,$lastName,$email,$employeeID);
    $newID = db_change($query,$updateValues,$con);
    if($_SESSION['role']==1||$_SESSION['role']==3||$_SESSION['role']==4){
        if($_POST['status']== true){
            $status = 1;
        }elseif($_POST['status']==false){
            $status = 0;
        }
        else{
            break;//<--THIS IS THE BREAK I'M TALKING ABOUT
        }
        $query = 'UPDATE USERS SET status = ? where idusers = ?';
        $updateValues = array($status, $employeeID);
        $newID = db_change($query,$updateValues,$con);
    }
    db_disconnect($con);
    break;
```

My instinct tells me that the `db_disconnect` function will still be executed but the `UPDATE USERS` query and it's associated lines will not be. Am I correct in thinking this? Thanks!

Comment: Surely it would be quicker to try it and see for yourself ;)

Comment: Depends on [`break $n;`](http://php.net/break).

Comment: I believe in this case it would break out of the switch case?

Comment: @mario *oh. my. god.* How am I only just learning about this *now*?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break` in PHP breaks exactly one level, in your case the `case`. To break more levels, use `break n`:

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it break just the `if`?

Comment: Because it says so in the documentation: `break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.`

Comment: So to ensure `db_disconnect` is still run I should execute it before the break? Also is there a comparable statement that allows for escaping an `if` statement?

Comment: @FrankB You can use a boolean flag or move around your `if / else` logic.

Comment: If you have to escape an `if` statement, your logic is wrong (you seem to have some kind of three-state boolean in your logic; fix that). There is no statement that I know of that can "break" an (higher level!) `if`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Actually there is a way: a good old `goto`. But that also points out to a wrong logic.

Comment: @MathieuImbert please don't give him any ideas ... :P

Comment: Everyone calm down... This is just me protecting my data. If the wrong type of data is sent I don't want it to execute the following query so that's why the third case is there, to prevent that from happening. I am open to suggestions for better ways to do it, but I don't want to stop the entire flow if that one variable is messed up.

Comment: @FrankB I understand. But you are doing it wrong. You have to **first** parse and validate user data (e.g. in `$_POST`), then use the validated data in your business logic. That way, you can be sure there is real boolean instead of this three-state thing.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm always learning (which is actually a big part of my job) so thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

> When a break is reached in PHP how many levels does it break out of?

1

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Depends on what?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - incorrect, the answer to the OP's question is in my answer

Comment: Fabian, learn to read the whole question. Do it too, when the question is long - sorry for that :(

Answer (score 1):

In your example, break will move out to the `switch` level, leaving your `case` statement.
`db_disconnect` will not be run.

Comment: db_disconnect is part of the case level, why won't it be run?

Comment: @FrankB - corrected (it breaks 'out of the case', not 'out to the case')